# How to configure $default path in AWS API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway

We are trying to leverage the $default path in AWS API gateway as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html

configured api gateway like this leveraging the **$default as one of the routes**

```
/
 /-default
   ANY
 /api
  /{proxy=}
```

when we are trying to invoke the api gateway on the **$default** path and GET call

```
https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/prod/test
```

we assumed it will invoke the **default path but it didn't**

```
message: "Missing Authentication Token"
```

but when we do

```
https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/prod/api/test
```

the **api integration is invoked**

**Note** : we already tried configuring **greedy path{proxy+}** instead of $default that does not work as the greedy path always takes precedence and /api routes also get routed to greedy path

Any help from the community in pointing us in the right direction would be of great help

Comment: I'm not sure, I think order matters. Shouldn't `default` be last?

Comment: @Marcin i don't think order matters even though i created default after /api ..it gets added before

Comment: @user2359997 It doesn't seem like you have created the `$default` path correctly. When creating the route for the HTTP API you have to specify `$default` as the `path` (the method can't be changed for this case). I tested this out and it works exactly as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html#http-api-develop-routes.evaluation). Could you confirm?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems like you have not set up your API Gateway HTTP API routes correctly causing the routing to not work [as expected](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html#http-api-develop-routes.evaluation). Would also like to mention that *HTTP APIs* and *REST APIs* are different types of [API Gateway APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-basic-concept.html), so do confirm that you have configured your API correctly.

Coming to how the routing would work, as a sample, here's how the *routes* for the API look:

[image: HTTP API routes]

1. Request to *GET* https://xxxx.execute-api.xxxx.amazonaws.com/prod/test : Routed to `$default` path
2. Request to *GET* https://xxxx.execute-api.xxxx.amazonaws.com/prod/api/test : Routed to `/api/{proxy+}` path

---

Further, if you have a greedy path at `ANY /{proxy+}`, then as you mentioned, this greedy path will take priority over the `$default` route. However, this would not take precedence over the `ANY /api` route if the request matches to the route, for example: *GET* https://xxxx.execute-api.xxxx.amazonaws.com/prod/api : would be routed to `/api` path and not `/{proxy+}`

The routing priority is also explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html#http-api-develop-routes.evaluation)

> After selecting a stage, API Gateway selects a route. API Gateway selects the route with the most-specific match, using the following priorities:
>
> 1. Full match for a route and method.
> 2. Match for a route and method with a greedy path variable (`{proxy+}`).
> 3. The `$default` route.
>
> If no routes match a request, API Gateway returns `{"message":"Not Found"}` to the client.

**EDIT**:

To create the `$default` route, just specify the path as `$default` when creating the route

[image: Create $default route]

Comment: thanks for the answer could you please let us know how we could configure the default path ? if possible with a screen shot ....

Comment: @user2359997 updated my answer to include that, pretty easy, nothing much to it really.

Comment: Important distinction to make is tha tthe `$default` path seems to only work for HTTP APIs, not REST APIs!